# Prototype callback function replace 'this' value

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, this

Alright, I have the sneaking suspicion that I am overlooking something really simple, but I am having an issue with the following code:

```
Array.prototype.sortArr = function (skey)
{
    var vals = new Array();
    for (key in this)
    {
        if (typeof(this[key][skey]) != 'undefined')
        {
            vals.push((this[key][skey]+'').toLowerCase());
        }
    }
    vals.sort();

    var newArr = new Array();
    for (i=0;i<vals.length;i++)
    {
        for (key in this)
        {
            if (typeof(this[key][skey]) != 'undefined')
            {
                if ((this[key][skey]+'').toLowerCase() == vals[i])
                {
                    newArr.push(this[key]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

Okay, in a nutshell, this function is similar to the sort function with the exception that it sorts through a multi-level object and I specify which keys it needs to sort by.
The issue is that I never actually replace or alter the 'this' value, meaning that this function doesn't actually do anything. For example:

```
var arr = new Array(new Array(1,5),new Array(2,0));
arr.sortArr(1);
```

It will not change the `arr` from before or after the `sortArr(1)` call. However, when I put an `alert(newArr)` right before the return of the function, it shows that it actually did reorder. So, my question is; how do I replace the `this` value in the callback function or at least return the proper/ new array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At the end of the function, instead of `return newArr;`, I think you would just do `this = newArr;`.

Comment: @Cory: this would only modify the reference, not the original object

Comment: @Cory: Like zerkms said, this doesn't work. On top of that, it gives a syntax error.

Comment: Hmm, then this is a good question. I'd be curious how to achieve this as well.

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you give context, like what you'll use this for?

Comment: @Battle_707: Also, using for..in might not give you the behavior you desire. You could end up with a new array of a different length than the original.

Comment: @PitaJ: I have a multi dimensional array in which each top level array value is another array. The primary array holds all of the different items, whereas the second level array contains a all of the item properties (e.g.: item name, item icon, item id). I then use this callback function to sort the primary array on a specific location in the secondary arrays.

Comment: @Cory: True, hence the `!='undefined'` check. What I planned with this method was to allow for objects to be handled as well (so, if the keys aren't numerical, this function would still work). However, I am not a 100% sure that is still working, so I might re-write the function (making it a little simpler) to simply do it using `for(i=0;i<vars.length;i++)` on all loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the current array at the end of your method, you would need to assign to its elements like this, copying all the elements into the current object's array before the end of the function:

```
this.length = newArr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    this[i] = newArr[i];
}
```

You could also use `.splice()` like this:

```
newArr.unshift(this.length);     // how many items to remove for .splice()
newArr.unshift(0);               // index for .splice() operation
this.splice.apply(this, newArr); // add the newArr elements
```

FYI, it's not generally correct to use the `for/in` construct on arrays because it will iterate properties on the object too in addition to array elements and that will often foul you up.  If you want to iterate the items in the array, use the traditional for loop like I did in my code snippet above.

Comment: I know the traditional for loop is better, but as I mentioned in another comment, I *do* want to keep the option to use this on objects too (don't worry, I already altered my code as I saw there were some flaws in it). As to your solution, it indeed works! Thank you very much. I tried a delete and then pushing the new values in the this array, but that left some nasty side effects.

Answer (score 0):

As you have it implemented, you're going to return a new array. If you want to replace your original array with the new result, you would have to do so explicitly:

```
var arr = new Array(new Array(1,5),new Array(2,0)); 
arr = arr.sortArr(1);
```

But it sounds like that's not what you want to do.

Comment: It actually *doesn't* return the newArr values. It's very misleading, as any other function would do this, but since it's a callback function, it doesn't simply return what I specify after the `return` (which I thought it would)

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArray = [{},"Bob",32].sortArr();
```

Think of your return statement not as going back out the top of the function...
...think of it as going out of the left-hand side.

So when you define your function, you put your parameters in the place of your arguments.
If you want to sort the object you're passing in, as-is, then you need to do your operations to the original object, AS-IS, without saving a copy of the object.

What I mean is:

```
function addBob (obj) {
    obj.name = "Bob";
    return undefined;
    // any fn without a return mentioned returns undefined, anyway.
    // I just put this here for reference.
}
```

This version of addBob will add name : "Bob" to the original object.

```
function addBob2 (obj) {
    bobject = obj;
    bobject.name = "Bob";
    return undefined;  // again, if you don't state a return, that's what you get
}
```

Okay.  Now we've got a problem.
Can you see it?

You've put an object into the top of your function, and you've saved a local copy of your object (sometimes, this is a good thing... but not here).

Then you modified your copy.

You think you're done.  But you're not.  Nothing changed.
Why?

Because you didn't save the changes back to the original.
There could be two ways of doing that:

1. function addBob3(obj) {
       var localObj = obj;
       localObj.name = "Bob";
       obj = localObj;
   }

   addBob3(externalObj);

This function is built to save a local-copy to do its calculations, but then once those calculations are done, it writes OVER the original object, or the object's property -- ie:

```
obj.name = localObj.name;
```

That will send the data back to the original object (ie: out of the top of the function).
Some people consider this bad practice, because if you've got dozens of these modify-in-place functions, it's hard to tell which objects have been modified by which functions, when you get into 10,000 line programs.

Don't worry too much about that right now.

The ***OTHER*** way to do it:

```
function addBob4(obj) {
    var localObj = obj;
    localObj.name = "Bob";
    return localObj;
}


var externalObj = { property1 : "something" },

newObj = addBob4(externalObj);
```

Now, you've got the return value going out to the ***LEFT*** of the function call.
newObj is going to be an object that's exactly like externalObj, except for the new additions you made to the copy.

So functions can exit through the left, if you capture the return in a variable.
And if you directly modify the object you pass in, in-place, those edits will apply to the original object/objects, after the function exits.

Working with "this" is a little tricky.
If it's an object, you can just do "this.name = 'Bob';" and you're done.

In the case of your array, you'd need a third loop, where you basically empty this[0] - this[this.length - 1], and then fill this[0] - this[newArr.length - 1], with the values from newArr.
Because JavaScript isn't going to let you explode "this" and turn it into a "this = X" statement.